# Python save to text file with utf-8 Hebrew shows as unicode \u05d9\u05dc\

Tags: python, string, unicode, hebrew

I want to save a dictionary object as json, but I am not able to read the file with notepad++. All the Hebrew charcthers converted to \u....

This is how I save it:

```
with open("users.json", "w", encoding='utf8') as write_file:
    json.dump(mydict, write_file)
```

In pycharm I do see the Hebrew properly.

Comment: `json.dump()` has an `ensure_ascii` parameter, which defaults to `True`. Set it to `False` to see non-ASCII characters literally.

Comment: Great thanks ! I still am not sure if python is a simple or complicated programming lang ...

Comment: @user8035311 I know my comment is technically an answer. But if one wants to act according to the book, the right thing to do would be finding a question-answer pair of which this post is a duplicate (I'm sure there is one).